# Join several rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

This is an example of the existing Data Frame:

```
   A    B    C    t
0  2.0  NaN  NaN  0.2
1  NaN  1.0  NaN  0.2
2  NaN  NaN  3.0  0.2
3  2.0  NaN  NaN  0.2
4  NaN  1.0  NaN  0.2
5  NaN  NaN  3.0  0.2
```

What I would like to have as a result looks like this:

```
   A  B  C    t
0  2  1  3  0.2
1  2  1  3  0.6
```

In this case the rows with the index 1&2 are inserted in the first row. This should also be possible for longer DataFrames with the same shape.

In addition the timestamp (Column 't') is the relative timestamp between the rows. This means there has to be an addition with the timestamps.

Thanks for the answers and sorry for the bad english :)

Comment: Looks like a sum over every 3 rows, with NaNs treated as 0.